# UIImageView does not follow the constraints that I applied

Tags: ios, swift

I have a parent, called `infoView`.  It has two children: `subLabel` and `tinyImageView`.    I'd like both of these children to be size 30.0, with subLabel first, followed by 10 pixel padding, followed by the tinyImageView.

For some reason, my tinyImageView is not respecting ANY of the constraints I put below. Even the height/width is not respected.

```
let boxSize = infoView.frame.size.height //30
let subLabel = UILabel()
subLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, boxSize, boxSize)
subLabel.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
subLabel.clipsToBounds = true
subLabel.backgroundColor = logoColor(1)
subLabel.text = String(post.subscribers)
subLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Lato-Bold", size: 13.0)
subLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
subLabel.textAlignment = .Center
infoView.addSubview(subLabel)

//Image

let tinyImageView = UIImageView(image:UIImage(named: "MO.jpg"))
tinyImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 2.5
tinyImageView.clipsToBounds = true
infoView.addSubview(tinyImageView)

let widthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: tinyImageView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: boxSize)
tinyImageView.addConstraint(widthConstraint)

let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: tinyImageView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: boxSize)
tinyImageView.addConstraint(heightConstraint)

print("------------")
let horizontalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: subLabel, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: tinyImageView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 10)
infoView.addConstraint(horizontalConstraint)

let verticalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: subLabel, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: tinyImageView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
verticalConstraint.active = true
```

The image turns out way too big, and the horizontal/vertical constraints don't work at all.  Currently, the image overlaps `subLabel`, as if it was just added without any constraints.

Comment: For views that are created programatically you have to explicitly set their `translatesAutoResizingMaskIntoContraints` property to false in order for constraints to apply correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Paulw11 stated in the comments, you need to set `translatesAutoResizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `false` for programmatically created views.  Also, your constraints will resize the frame for your `UIImageView`, but they won't scale the image.  For that, you need to set the `contentMode` property:

```
tinyImageView.translatesAutoResizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
tinyImageView.contentMode = .ScaleToFill
```

Values you probably want to consider for `contentMode` are `.ScaleToFill` (scale to fit area distorting aspect ratio if necessary), `.ScaleAspectFit` (maintain aspect ratio and leave part of the view as transparent if necessary) and `.ScaleAspectFill` (maintain aspect ratio and clip part of image if necessary).

Answer (score 0):

From your code, I just saw one activation for constraint `verticalConstraint`.

active all the constraints you add.

if your constraints got conflicted, 
Set `translatesAutoResizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `false`(usually if you set constraints programmatically, you set it to false)